# Calculating $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\infty,\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: limits, analysis

Please help me calculate the:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\infty,\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$$
My attempt is: First method: for $t>0$ we have $e^t\geq \frac{t^3}{3}$ now i have:

$$(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}\leq\frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{(x+y)}\rightarrow 0, (x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,\infty)$$
but i dint know how to continue

second method:the polar coord
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\infty,\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}=\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}(r^2)e^{-r(cos\theta+sin\theta)}=\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{r^2}{e^{r(cos\theta+sin\theta)}}=\frac{1}{cos\theta+\sin\theta}\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2r}{e^r}=\frac{2}{cos\theta+\sin\theta}\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^r}=\frac{2}{cos\theta+\sin\theta}\cdot0=0$$ i use the L'Hopital rule,but i dint know its correct

Comment: I mean, $(x^2 + y^2) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to 0$ and $e^{-(x+y)} \to 1$ as $(x,y) \to 0$. Now use some arithmetic of limits to conclude that the whole limit is $0$.

Comment: i corrected, I had written it wrong

Comment: I think $x^2+y^2<(x+y)^2$ and set $t=x+y$ with $\lim t^2e^{-t}=0$ is probably simpler.

Comment: please can you explain your method in more detail

Comment: What do you mean when you say you don't know how to continue at the end of your first attempt? Aside from a typo (the denominator under the $3(x^2+y^2)$ should be $(x+y)^3$, not just $(x+y)$), it looks like you've given a complete solution there.

Comment: Your proof with the polar co-ordinates is wrong, first of all $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, then $\lim \frac{r^2}{e^{r(\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta))}}=0$ but not because of the steps you have showed, apply the l'hopital properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $ e^t > \frac{t^4}{4!}$, we have for $x,y >0$
$$e^{x+y} > \frac{(x+y)^4}{4!} = \frac{(x^2+y^2+2xy)^2}{4!} > \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{4!} $$
$$(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)} < 4! \frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}=\frac{4!}{(x^2+y^2)} \to 0$$

Comment: The inequality $$\frac{(x^2+y^2+2xy)^2}{4!} > \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{4!}$$ is not always true, indeed it is false for $\;y=-x\;.$

Comment: $x,y$ are positive here

Answer (score 1):

Your method of showing that $r^2\exp(-r[\cos\theta+\sin\theta])$ is also correct. The only thing you need to consider to the finish line, is that the angle $\theta$ must fall within $[0,\pi/2]$, causing the term $\cos\theta+\sin\theta$ to be at least $\sqrt 2/2$. Then you can conclude the final limit.

A different approach can be taken by noting that for $x,y>0$
$$
0<(x^2+y^2)e^{-x-y}=x^2e^{-x-y}+y^2e^{-x-y}<x^2e^{-x}+y^2e^{-y}
$$
and the conclusion comes very easily.

Comment: how can we end sir

Comment: The rightmost function tends to $0$ when $x,y\to \infty$ since both $x^2\exp(-x)$ and $y^2\exp(-y)$ do. Use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: $$0<(x^2+y^2)e^{-x-y}=x^2e^{-x-y}+y^2e^{-x-y}<x^2e^{-x}+y^2e^{-y}                      \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\infty,\infty)}x^2e^{-x}+y^2e^{-y}=                                             
 \lim_{(x\rightarrow \infty}x^2e^{-x}+\lim_{(x\rightarrow \infty}y^2e^{-y}=0$$ or not correct

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what I take to be a typo (the denominator under the $3(x^2+y^2)$ should be $(x+y)^3$, not just $(x+y)$), your first method looks fine. It could be elaborated to

$$(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}\le{3(x^2+y^2)\over(x+y)^3}={3x^2\over(x+y)^3}+{3y^2\over(x+y)^3}\le{3x^2\over x^3}+{3y^2\over y^3}={3\over x}+{3\over y}\to0+0=0$$

Comment: Can I ask a question, are such limits for school students (≤11 th grade) in textbooks?

Comment: @lonestudent, you'd have to look at some highschool level textbooks. The concept of limit is usually introduced initially for functions of a single variable ($x$ or $n$), and only later for functions of two or more variables, where there are subtleties that can arise in attempts to determine whether limits exist.